# How to convert a V4 bot to a Skill?

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

We are planning to add existing bot which is V4 to our Universal Bot which is in Virtual Assistant template.
For this we have come up with the Skill based approach via which we can add skills to existing VA.
The challenge which we are facing now is that we couldn't find link which was there earlier to convert existing V4 bot to skill (https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/skills/tutorials/convert-v4-bot/csharp/2-add-packages/).
and the link which there in FAQ section(https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/help/faq/ ) under "How do I convert an existing v4 Bot to a Bot Framework Skill?" redirects me to a Microsoft page implementing a skill (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/skill-implement-skill?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs)

The current document has section of migrating Virtual Assistant to Bot framework Skill(Migrate existing Virtual Assistant to Bot Framework Skills GA).
but I cannot find any page in updated document which can guide me to convert existing V4 Bot to skill.

Please help us with the same.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your problem is solved on GitHub in this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/issues/3260). For others with a similar issue, here is the explanation.

> The link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/skill-implement-skill?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs described how to implement a skill. **If your bot is based on the BotBuilder SDK greater than or equals to 4.7.0, then your bot is automatically a skill.** Virtual Assistant that's created based on the Virtual Assistant Template that's greater than or equals to the 0.7 release will be able to connect to a skill without extra work.

Hope this helps.